# How do I get rid of the unsupported packages mentioned during the upgrade from Lucid to Maverick?

Tags: package-management

When upgrading from Lucid to Maverick using the update manager, at one point it lists the packages that are no longer supported (i.e. f-spot). It does not say that it's going to uninstall them. After the upgrade is complete, they are still there. How can I get rid of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most cases you don't particularly have to remove those packages. That notice only means that those packages are no longer in Ubuntu's *main* component, and have been demoted to *Universe* (see [this page](http://www.ubuntu.com/project/about-ubuntu/components) for more information on components), which means that support for them is still available from the Ubuntu community.

If you still want to remove them, you can find out which packages they were by looking at the upgrade log (/var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log) in which you'll find a line that begins with "demoted:" containing a list of the packages demoted.

If you want to remove packages that are absolutely unused, `sudo apt-get autoremove` will do that.

Comment: I know I don't have to, but I *want* to

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: perfect, thank you. to take it to the end, I grabbed all the packages and threw them all at one big "apt-get remove"

Comment: I suggest using `aptitude markauto <packages>` because with this the packages don't get uninstalled if they are needed by other packages.

Comment: I know this an old question/answer but just a tip for anyone still looking for this information: You likely have more unsupported packages then what was listed at the time of a distribution upgrade (those are just the packages for which support was dropped after the upgrade not the ones that were already not supported). Also `sudo apt-get autoremove` is not meant to, and likely will not remove these unsupported packages (see documentation for autoremove parameter). I think the correct answer is @gaurav-paliwal 's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/951085/344285).

Answer (score 7):

If you want to remove unsupported packages then first list them using `ubuntu-support-status --show-unsupported`
then use `sudo apt remove <package-name or names>`

You will then get rid of unsupported packages